# Why is IPV6 not working

Tags: apache-2.2, debian, ipv6

I have ipv6.domain.tld set up and pointing to my server's IPV6 address. I have added my server's IPV6 address through Webmin. When I restart Apache, I get

```
Restarting web server: apache2[Mon Jul 16 02:51:57 2012] [error] (EAI 2)Name or service not known: Failed to resolve server name for 2607:5300:20:101::1:1023 (check DNS) -- or specify an explicit ServerName
 ... waiting [Mon Jul 16 02:51:58 2012] [error] (EAI 2)Name or service not known: Failed to resolve server name for 2607:5300:20:101::1:1023 (check DNS) -- or specify an explicit ServerName
.
```

When I try to visit ipv6.domain.tld, I just get a domain down page. What is wrong with it?

Comment: What's the `ServerName` configuration for that virtual host?  Looks like there isn't one, so it's guessing at the name based on the (non-existent) reverse DNS for that address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `VirtualHost` in which you've used the IPv6 address requires a `ServerName` to be set. If you aren't using `VirtualHost` then you need to set the global `ServerName`.

Comment: Remember to accept the answer that solved your problem by clicking the outline of the check mark next to it. Welcome to Server Fault!

Answer (score 0):

In Apache configuration files you must often enclose the IPv6 address between [ and ] to avoid confusion between the :'s in the address and the : between the address and the optionsl port number.

Comment: That was done by Webmin. It does have it in brackets.